# resolver el error 'could not load type xxx from assembly yyy'

Tags: c#, test, dependencyinjection

este es el error que tengo:

> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcJsonMvcCoreBuilderExtensions'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json,
> Version=3.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

como veis, el paquete esta instalado, y mis using statements son los siguientes:

```
using AngleSharp.Html.Dom;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;
```

supongo que salta en los using porque ni siquiera salta el constructor de la clase,

alguna idea? Se trata de integration tests.

Los integration tests se basan en core 3.1 pero la api que se testea es 2.x, puede ser por eso?

Comment: revisa el target framework. Ese error puede ser por tener en tu solucion mezcla de net core 2.X con 3.0

Comment: Es por eso probablemente. En net 3.0 hubo [cambios importantes](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325) como la eliminacion de Json.net que posiblemente estan dando ese problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema está en que un projecto estaba en 2.2 y otro en 3.1, entonces la solución cascaba porque no sabía cual cargar.

Solucion: migrar a 3.1